# Pass string to dll

Tags: c#, string, dll, char, hwndhost

How to call a function in c++ dll from C# WPF application with string parametrs? I add dll to C# app through "Add References", not "[DLLImport]"

All problem is that C# suggests function with 'sbyte*' parametr, not 'char*'. Functions with 'int' parametrs works perfect.

Here is code:

My function in c++ dll:

```
public ref class OpenGLHwnd : public HwndHost   
{
public:
    void myFunc(char* name)
    {
        // some code
    }
```

C# code:

```
HwndHost host = new WPFOpenGLLib.OpenGLHwnd();
HWNDPlaceholder.Child = host;
(HWNDPlaceholder.Child as WPFOpenGLLib.OpenGLHwnd).myFunc("aaaa");
```

myFunc want 'sbyte*' parametr, not 'char*'. Why?

Or tell, please, how to convert string to sbyte*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your C++ DLL is apparently a .NET assembly (`ref class`, i.e. C++/CLI), you can just pass the string as .NET `String`:

```
#include <msclr/marshal.h>
using namespace msclr::interop;

public ref class OpenGLHwnd : public HwndHost   
{
public:
    void myFunc(System::String^ name)
    {
        marshal_context^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
        const char* ptr = context->marshal_as<const char*>(name);
        puts(ptr);
        delete context;
    }
```